# android:gesture with onclick

Tags: android, onclick, gesture

I have a layout with many buttons on it.I want to click them individually and I also want gestures to work, mainly left and right flings. Please help me solve this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

No problem Vishnu,
Here's how you go about solving those problems:

1.) Set onClickListeners for each of your buttons (i.e :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{ ...

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{ ...
```

2.) For your left and right flings I suggest you look here, this is an excellent and easy to adapt tutorial for flings of all sort: http://www.damonkohler.com/2011/07/android-fling-detection.html

Cheers

Comment: will the flings work over all views? or shud i set any listeners to the views?

Comment: @VishnuMohanG you will have to declare this:   
          
private FlingDetector flingDetector;

in each of your **ACTIVITIES** and then flingDetector = new FlingDetector(new FlingListener() {
      Override
      public void onTopToBottom() {

      }

      Override
      public void onRightToLeft() {

      }

      Override
      public void onLeftToRight() {

      }

      Override
      public void onBottomToTop() {

      }
    });  in the onCreate() method of your activity and don't forget

Comment: you will also have to re-route the TouchEvents on your activity to the flinddetector:   @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (flingDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

Comment: shud i register it with all views on the screen? could ya please show me an example how to register it with a button? 
Thank You.

Comment: @VishnuMohanG could you post the code from your views? post it as an edit in your original question. If that's not possible then use pastebin.com to paste your code and provide me with the url

Comment: its just relative layout with a set of 4 or 5 linear layouts with 4 buttons in each.

Comment: @VishnuMohanG oh, so all of these layouts and buttons lie in the same activity? Then you won't need to declare the FlingDetector multiple times, i.e you will only have to declare the FlingDetector once in the Activity where you declare all your linear layouts and buttons.

Comment: so, we just needa declare it, not assign it to views like we assign listeners.

Comment: @VishnuMohanG Firstly, I'd advice you to look at this link and examine the code provided here (scroll down to see how the detector is used in an activity. Secondly, if that doesn't help, you need to provide me with your code so I can better understand what you are trying to say. There really isn't much more I can say without seeing your code.

Comment: Well, i just wanna know if the layout is filled with buttons, if i fling over buttons, will this work? there is no space in the layout without buttons. also, i have a scrollview in which the buttons are packed.

Comment: Logically, yes, even if you fling over buttons this will work as your fling will be detected as a fling over the entire view. But in your case, as you say you have a scrollview I can't guarantee if it'll work. Can you implement the code I've been pointing you to (http://www.damonkohler.com/2011/07/android-fling-detection.html) and see what happens, if it works then I'll have been glad to help you, if not, can you tell me what problem is? You need to make an effort as well.

Comment: its working in blank areas, if i start the swipe over a button, it wont work. I f i start at a blank space it works.

Comment: @VishnuMohanG Can you provide me with your code so I can try and find a solution on my computer. This way I can solve the issue and give you the corrected code. Just provide me with the code of the view/Activity where you are trying to implement the Fling detection.